# How to change angular scope values using Casperjs

Tags: angularjs, node.js, phantomjs, casperjs, bitbucket-pipelines

I was trying to automate some test cases for an angular booking app I was working on ,where I wanted to write a test case that was to be integrated with bitbucket pipeline. I found casperjs easy to start with.

There came a stage when I had to change the `$scope` values of the app . 
Here is how I did it .

Answer (score 0):

CasperJS (also phantomjs) comes with an `evaluate()` method that takes a function inside which we could access the current page DOM context . It is recently that I understood how `eval` works wherever it be. Angular also comes with the `angular.element(<element>).scope()` that lets you access the scope of that particular element . In my case I wanted to change the `start_time` and `end_time` of a booking before clicking submit .

```
  casper.evaluate(function () {
    var scope = angular.element('booking-element').scope()
    var bookingForm = scope.booking;
    bookingForm.start_time = "2017-09-05 12:00";
    bookingForm.end_time = "2017-09-05 16:00"
    scope.$apply();
  });
```

A `casper.click('.submit-button')` should be submit the button for you with the updated values .

Comment: Did you just ask a question and immediately answer it?

Comment: Yeah , found something . wanted to share it . As you would know wanted checked the `Share your knowledge`.

Comment: If you're trying to build reputation here, I suggest answering *actual* questions.

Comment: I am doing that too .